# RuntimeError: XTC read error: Compressed 3d coordinate

Tags: python

Iam trying to compute tica coordinates for a protein,

I get a error with
`pyemma.coordinates.load(xtc, features=feat)`
xtc is the .xtc file while features are distances i computed as follows :

```
feat = pyemma.coordinates.featurizer(t)
feat.add_distances(pairs1, periodic= True)
```

I get the following error with :

```
reader = pyemma.coordinates.source(traj, features=feat, chunksize=1000) 
                          
data = pyemma.coordinates.load(xtc, features=feat)
```

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-3bc104192932> in <module>()
      1 
----> 2 data = pyemma.coordinates.load(xtc, features=feat)

    242                  or len(trajfiles) is 0)):
    243         reader = create_file_reader(trajfiles, top, features, chunksize=cs, **kw)
--> 244         trajs = reader.get_output(stride=stride)
    245         if len(trajs) == 1:
    246             return trajs[0]

/users/hsahni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyemma/coordinates/data/_base/datasource.py in get_output(self, dimensions, stride, skip, chunk)
    404             pg.register(it.n_chunks, description='getting output of %s' % self.__class__.__name__)
    405             with pg.context(), it:
--> 406                 for itraj, chunk in it:
    407                     i = slice(it.pos, it.pos + len(chunk))
    408                     assert i.stop - i.start > 0

/users/hsahni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyemma/coordinates/data/_base/datasource.py in __next__(self)
   1047         self._select_file(self._itraj)
   1048         try:
-> 1049             X = self._use_cols(self._next_chunk())
   1050             self._t += len(X)
   1051         except StopIteration as e:

/users/hsahni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyemma/coordinates/data/_base/datasource.py in _next_chunk(self)
   1166             x = self._it._next_chunk()
   1167         else:
-> 1168             x = next(self._it)
   1169         # We discard the trajectory index here for transformation
   1170         if self.transform_function is not None:

/users/hsahni/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyemma/coordinates/util/patches.py in __next__(self)
    212             if self._extension not in _TOPOLOGY_EXTS:
    213                 traj = self._f.read_as_traj(self._topology, n_frames=n_frames,
--> 214                                             stride=self._stride, your text`atom_indices=self._atom_indices, **self._kwargs)
    215             else:
    216                 traj = self._f.read_as_traj(n_frames=n_frames,

mdtraj/formats/xtc/xtc.pyx in mdtraj.formats.xtc.XTCTrajectoryFile.read_as_traj()

mdtraj/formats/xtc/xtc.pyx in mdtraj.formats.xtc.XTCTrajectoryFile.read()

mdtraj/formats/xtc/xtc.pyx in mdtraj.formats.xtc.XTCTrajectoryFile._read()

RuntimeError: XTC read error: Compressed 3d coordinate
```

I was expecting no error and the function returns the reader object.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the specific error message you encountered when running the code. Additionally, providing information about the versions of the relevant libraries (e.g., pyemma, mdtraj) could assist in understanding the issue better. Consider including any additional steps you have taken to resolve the error. Clarifying these points will help reviewers provide more accurate and targeted feedback.

Comment: Hello there, pyemma uses mdtraj as its I/O layer and not MDAnalysis. These are two different packages. Therefore, I removed the "MDAnalysis" tag.

Comment: I would try loading the XTC into [mdtraj](https://www.mdtraj.org/1.9.8.dev0/index.html) and see if the error persists. If yes, then check the trajectory with the GROMACS `gmx check` command. If this command does _not_ give any errors then it's a problem with mdtraj. If you get an error from `gmx check` then your XTC file is corrupted.